How to Configure Bitnami Redis Helm Chart to Deploy Each Redis Instance and Sentinel in Separate Pods
I am using the terraform which using Bitnami Redis Helm chart to deploy Redis on Kubernetes and need to configure it so that each Redis instance and Sentinel runs in its own separate pod. Currently, I have a setup where Redis master and slave, along with Sentinel, are co-located in the same pods.
Here’s a snippet of my main.tf file:
resource "helm_release" "redis" {
  name       = "redis"
  namespace  = "redis"
  chart      = "redis"
  repository = "oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts"
  version    = "20.0.5"
  create_namespace = true
  values = [
    <<-EOF

    persistence:
      enabled: true
      existingClaim: ${kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim.longhorn_pvc.metadata[0].name}

    master:
      persistence:
        enabled: false

    replica:
      persistence:
        enabled: false
      replicaCount: 2

    sentinel:
      enabled: true
    
    auth:
      password: ${var.redis_password}

    ingress:
      enabled: true
      annotations: {}
      hosts:
        - host: ${var.redis_host}
          paths:
            - /
      tls: []

    EOF
  ]

  depends_on = [rke_cluster.k8s, local_file.kubeconfig]
}

However, deploying with this configuration results in Redis master and slave being co-located with Sentinel containers in the same pods. After running terraform apply command, k8s cluster includes these pods with redis namespace:
root@m:~/tf-infra$ kubectl get pods -n redis
NAME           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
redis-node-0   2/2     Running   0          122m
redis-node-1   2/2     Running   0          122m

I want to achieve the following pod configuration:

redis-node-0: Contains only the Redis master
redis-node-1: Contains only the Redis slave
sentinel-node-1: Contains only one Sentinel instance, port: 26379
sentinel-node-2: Contains only one Sentinel instance, port: 26380
sentinel-node-3: Contains only one Sentinel instance, port: 26381

How can I modify the values.yaml or Helm chart to ensure that each instance (master, replica, and Sentinel) is deployed in a separate pod?
Now I am testing it on one linux server.
Next step will be deploying each node to different linux servers with terraform.
auth:
  enabled: true
  password: ${var.redis_password}

master:
  persistence:
    enabled: false
  replicaCount: 1

replica:
  replicaCount: 1
  persistence:
    enabled: false

sentinel:
  enabled: true
  replicaCount: 3


I expected this configuration to create 5 separate pods:

One pod for the Redis master
One pod for the Redis replica
Three pods for Sentinel instances

However, after applying this configuration, I only see two pods: redis-node-0 and redis-node-1. Each of these pods contains two containers: one for Redis (master or replica) and one for Sentinel.
